# JackRabbit setup on WAS for one of our REST application

Tags: java, linux, websphere, jackrabbit-oak

[image]We are trying to setup JackRabbit Oak on one of our Linux machine with IBM WAS application server and facing some issues starting the sever on WAS.

The Apache JackRabbit is a content repository which is a hierarchical content store with support for structured and unstructured content, full text search, versioning, transactions, observation, and more. We are using it for storing digital assets in structured form (specifically, as a tree) as per our requirement.

We have a REST application and another application DAM (Digital Asset Management) which handles creation of repository, providing connection with the repo whenever requested (Singleton), creating nodes, etc. on the repository. In our local development setup we have exported this DAM as a JAR, say dam.jar and have put this in REST application’s class path. We have JackRabbit Oak’s JAR (oak-run-1.4.11.jar), which we have put in class path of DAM application.

While doing a similar setup on Linux machine on WAS application server, we are using the same dam.jar which is created by exporting the project as a JAR in eclipse on Windows machine. We put this in REST application’s class path on WAS by configuring this in the server on which REST app is deployed.

While debugging we found that application is able to access classes from dam.jar, but when DAM’s class tries to call JackRabbit’s classes it fails throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. We tried putting JackRabbit’s JAR (oak-run-1.4.11.jar) in the class path on WAS by configuring this for REST app’s server, but then server fails to start.

Attached is the log file: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/servers/RESTAPP/configuration/1489493294429.log
There is nothing much inside server logs from /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/RESTAPP (RESTAPP is the server name for our REST application), below is the snippet:

*[3/14/17 17:38:04:872 IST] 00000001 ModelMgr      I   WSVR0801I: Initializing all server configuration models
[3/14/17 17:38:08:564 IST] 00000001 WorkSpaceMana A   WKSP0500I: Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled.
[3/14/17 17:38:08:834 IST] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
[3/14/17 17:38:18:241 IST] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. Server logs, startServer.log, and other log files under /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/RESTAPP should contain failure information.*

We suspect dam.jar here, as this has been created from our eclipse workspace by exporting it as a JAR file and this might need some extra information to have this JackRabbit Oak libraries included in that.

We are putting classpath entries in Application servers > RESTAPP > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine of WAS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a "Shared library" in Websphere and putting your JackRabbit dependency jars in there:

Environment -> Shared libraries -> New...

Set then name "Jackrabbit", and then in the Classpath box add the paths to your jars.

Then in your REST application  (Applications -> Application Types -> WebSphere enterprise applications -> [your application name])

Click "Shared library references" under "References"

Select the application and click "Reference shared libraries"

Select the Jackrabbit shared library and click the right arrow to reference that shared library from the application.

Classloading in WebSphere is very complicated -- see chapter 22 of the *WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Administration and Configuration Guide* for the full description. Trying to add classpath entries at the JVM definition level definitely won't work.

Comment: I tried the shared library approach suggested by Andrew. Now, the server is able to start.
But, the REST services don't work.

Comment: I added an image of stacktrace to the original question, with reference to earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on Andrew's answer above, the real key is to make sure that both dam.jar and oak-run-1.4.11.jar are within the same class loader, and that they are NOT in a server-level class loader - putting custom code in the server JVM class path makes it visible to the server runtime and can actually override server classes (which is probably why your server init failed after doing that).

The very easiest answer, assuming this is a simple web application, is to put both jars in the WEB-INF directory of your WAR module.  Both will be loaded by the web app class loader, and they'll be able to see each other.  If there's some reason you don't want them in the application itself, then Andrew's shared library suggestion would have the same practical effect.